# How could I find the JDK path for Launch4j?

Tags: java

I want to know the path for my JDK but I only found the path for my JRE.
I try to acces cmd but didn t help.
C:\Users\babic>java -version
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you try looking at your Environment Variables? Assuming Win 10, types 'advanced system settings' in your search bar, select System Settings control panel, click Environment Variables button and look at your PATH setting.

Comment: You might try a Powershell approach: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34637.powershell-list-and-export-installed-programs-local-or-remote.aspx